# Multi-column listviews

Tags: android, layout, android-listview

Is it possible to define a *different* multi-column approach for a list view in portrait and landscape? For example on the Android market you have two columns when scrolling through apps in portrait mode but 3 columns in landscape.

I couldn't see a way of defining two "positions" within one layout row in the custom adapters and no way of specifying that the ListView has two different list items within one row. Should I be using a different sort of layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Market App is not using a ListView it is using a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) see the [Hello GridViewTutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) for more info.

A GridView can use the same Adapter as a listview but it will position items in a grid with multiple columns. You could either specify the number of columns in a ressource file and then distinguish with values-port values-xhdpi etc. or you can make the GridView to choose for itself [how many columns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#AUTO_FIT) should be shown.

Comment: Thanks Janusz. That's perfect - exactly what I was looking for. For my menu view I didn't even need to set different files for portrait and landscape. By setting a column width I could force the grid view to do all the work. For some of my more complicated ListViews I need a divider but this isn't supported by the GridView. What's the best way to achieve this? Add a background image to the items with a stroke outline?

Comment: That would be my solution, just put the divider into the items. This is only a problem if you want to have a divider that is only between two columns and not also on the left and right side

Comment: It looks like the market puts a divider on the left and bottom of each row. I can only seem to get the stroke to operate on all four sides of the item - which obviously means you get double lines between rows/columns. I guess I need some kind of 9 image with a line on the left and bottom and can't just express it in XML.

Answer (score 2):

If you add the two folders :

```
layout-land
layout-port
```

In each of these folders there is the same file, say `myRowLayout.xml`

When your device is in landscape mode, `myRowLayout.xml` that is in the folder `layout-land` will be used, while that in `layout-port` will be used when in portrait mode.